# Create Func to return both reference- and value-types

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I have a method returning a `Func<object>` built by an expression as follows:

```
var expr = Expression.Property(
        Expressions.Expression.Constant(new Foo { Name = "Hans", Age = 3 }, typeof(Foo)), 
        "Age");
var f = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(expr).Compile();
```

This expression should return the `Age`-property of this dummy `Foo`-object. The problem is that as I want to return a `Func<object>` instead of a `Func<int>` I get an

> ArgumentException: An expression of type `System.Int32` cannot be used as return-type `System.Object`. (or something similar, have german version).

If I´d chose the `Name`-property instead of the `Age`-property the same works. I know this has to do with boxing and unboxing as `int` does not extend `object`.

However how may I return the appropriate function that represents a value-type-property?

Comment: Cast Age = 3 to object: Age = (object) 3

Comment: `Age` is an `int`-property, so this won´t compile I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Expression.Convert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292051%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to cast the integer to an `object` like this:

```
var expr = Expression.Convert(
    Expression.Property(
        Expression.Constant(
            new Foo {Name = "Hans", Age = 3},
            typeof (Foo)),
        "Age"),
    typeof(object));
```